# Extract part of a std::vector<char> to a const char*?

Tags: c++, vector, char

Would would be the simplest way to extract part of a `vector<char>` (assuming I knew the indices) to end up with a `const char*`? I need to do this so that I can pass the const char* in to `atoi()` and `atol()`.

EDIT:

```
    long pp;
    int qq;
    memcpy( &pp, &My_Vector[25], 8);
    memcpy( &qq, &My_Vector[19], 4);

    q= qq;
    p= static_cast<double>(pp)/1E8;
```

However, when the function finishes:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'pp.51040' was
>   corrupted.

Comment: Something like `&vec[i]` perhaps. Or `vec.data()` Just guessing here.

Comment: atoi() requires a pojinter to a null terminated character string, not a pointer to a single character!

Comment: The string "0V)20" does not represent a valid number.

Comment: @Pat its represented in binary form (so its a big number). I have just represented the binary digits as chars (the ascii values still represent the number). Originally I wrote custom code to calculate the number, but i think i have a bug so i wanted to stick to using atol().

Comment: Of course not!  atol() converts null terminated ascii to binary.  The leading 0 will be interpreted as the null terminating an empty string.

Comment: @ravenspoint ok i was lead to believe I could..... based on the fact I have this vector<char> and within it, 8 of the chars/bytes form a long, how could I extract these to use within atol()? (sorry for the confusion)

Comment: The a in atol means ascii.  You cannot use that function to convert binary to binary - if that means anything.  Just do a memcopy.

Comment: You are copying 4 bytes into long qq - half the memory will contain garbage!

Comment: (I did change my code from long to int for qq) they contain the values I am expecting: qq = 5323 and pp = 841569792

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42156/discussion-between-user997112-and-ravenspoint)

Comment: OK.  So you conversion was successful.  Something ales is going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

An std::vector guarantees to store all its elements sequentially, so &vec[i] should work. But that does not mean that the pointer will be zero-terminated. You need a zero-terminated string  for use with atoi or atol.

The safest way would be to copy it to an std::string

```
std::string tmp(&vec[i], 9); // if substring is 9 characters long
```

Now use tmp.c_str(), this is guaranteed to be zero-terminated.

Comment: In C++11, you can also use `vec.data() + i` instead of `&vec[i]`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working- i'll put an edit in my question.

Comment: I have put the contents of the 8 bytes in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
const char* c = tmp.c_str();
p = atol(c);
```

The results in undefined behaviour, because the pointer returned from c_str() is temporary.

Try this:

```
p = atol( tmp.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
memcpy( &p, &My_Vector[25], 8);
```

or

```
p = * ((long *) &My_Vector[25]);
```

Always assuming the byte order is correct.

Comment: Just to confirm, what type should p be in your first possibility? I ask because I declared p as a long and then I ended up with a stack corruption run-time error.

Comment: memcpy does not care - it uses void*

Comment: Hmmm- I have put my code in the original question (and the error message). If you could help it would be greatly appreciated.